# Need to subscribe to 3rd party webhook to get notified of events

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I am working with an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project. I need to subscribe to 3rd party webhook to get notified of the events. I believe I need to create the receiver part. can someone please help with that, I am new to it.

Comment: You need an endpoint that matches the requirements that the third party should provide.